# How to translate QgsMapCanvas coordinates to wgs-84?

Tags: qgis, postgis

My application uses QgsMapCanvas.

I've got point coordinates in wgs-84 crs and i need to add this point to vector layer (represents postgis table) inside of the canvas.

Have no idea how to transform correctly wgs-84 coordinates to canvas/layer crs. 
Can anyone help me? Is there any python/c++ examples?